# How can I use the same CompositionConainer object (or it's contained assemblies) across my solution?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef, system.componentmodel

Let me explain a very simplistic example of what I need.  Let's say that I have a VS solution that uses MEF and has the following, broad structure of projects and classes.

1. Server (Project)

   - Server.cs (Contains `Main` method, for launching the app.)
2. Shared (Project)

   - \Contracts

     - ILogger.cs
     - ISettings.cs
3. Settings (Project)

   - MySettings.cs (class implementing ISettings)
4. Logger (Project

   - MyLogger.cs (class implementing ILogger)

Given...

- All of the above projects reference the Shared project.
- Server is the starting application, which initializes all catalogs into an application container.

...I can start an application and initialize a singleton of `MySettings` and `MyLogger` from within my `Server` application.  So far, so good.

Now, let's assume that `MyLogger` needs to access a settings file for an output directory.  The value for the directory location is stored in the `MySettings` object, which is initialized in `Server.cs` into a `CompositonContainer`.

Since I'm using MEF, I do not want to have to reference the `Settings` project, within the `Logger` project.  Instead, I'd like to use MEF to get the current applications  `ISettings` singleton, which was initialized at the start of my `Server` application and exists withing the servers `CompositionContainer`.

How can I properly access the `MySettings` singleton from within `MyLogger` using MEF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server:

```
 class Services
 {
     [Import]
     public ISettings Settings 
     { 
         get; set;
     }

     [Import]
     public ILogger Logger 
     {
        get;  set;
     }

 }


 static void Main()
 {
     AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
     catalog.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SettingsProject.MySettings));
     catalog.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(LoggerProject.MyLogger));


     Services services = new Services();

     CompositionContainer cc = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
     cc.ComposeParts(services);

     // services properties are initialized           

 }
```

Settings Project

```
 [Export(typeof(ISettings)]
 class MySettings
 {
 }
```

Logger project

```
 [Export(typeof(ILogger)]
 class MyLogger : ILogger
 {
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyLogger(ISettings settings)
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thabk you for answering!  When I get back to my office on Monday, I'll verify this.  This appears to be the solution.